# How to load the below JSON data into Pyspark with separate rows for each value for selected attribute

Tags: python, json, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Select all JSON attribute value with the given attribute string name in PySpark

Tried using from_json with schema and also used get_json_object with path. Always displays null.

the JSON is read from text file which contains other text data.

> random
>
> text
>
> lol
>
> funny
>
> ,.cm,.ssndfnklsdfsdnfo
>
> snsnksd
>
> lol | BFF JSON :
>   {"bookingSource":"nothere","flightNumber":"AA1234","alternateSlices":{"Thursday"
>   : [{"segments":[{"cabin":"Economy"}]}]},"Friday" :
>   [{"segments":[{"cabin":"Business"}]}]}

I loaded the file using

> sc =
>   SparkSession.builder.appName("test1").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
>
> file = sc.readStream.option("maxFilesPerTrigger", 1).text('sample')
>
> jsonLines = file.filter(file.value.contains("BFF JSON"))\
>               .select(split(file['value'],"BFF JSON :").getItem(1).alias("json"))
>
> converted = jsonLines\
>               .withColumn("bookingSource", get_json_object("json", "$.bookingSource"))\
>               .withColumn("flightNumber", get_json_object("json", "$.flightNumber"))\
>               .withColumn("cabin",get_json_object("json", "$..cabin"))

But always the cabin is coming as null. Does the JsonPath wildcard won't work here? How can I get the cabin attribute occurring anywhere in the JSON without need for parent attribute.

Currently getting :
[image: Current output]

But expected:
[image: Expectedd]